# If a standard form needs some format corrections described in the OA, should the resubmitted form be re-dated or should it keep its original date?

Tags: ids, forms

Specifically it is an Information Disclosure Statement in which some dates for non-patent refs were missing, but no new references are being added.

Comment: I don't know, but if you need to know fast, calling the uspto or the examiner should get you an answer (please add it here then).

Answer (score 0):

I have been told by someone at the USPTO that it really doesn't matter whether the revised IDS form's date is revised to the date of resubmission or just kept with its original date. Not sure this was a reliable answer but that's the response I received.